# Emacs for Python programming: module/class outline/browser

Tags: python, emacs, navigation

I am currently using https://github.com/fgallina/python.el + ropemacs, but I am missing module browser: separate buffer that outlines names defined in the current module (list of classes with their methods). Google says that there are OO-browser and emacs-code-browser, but they looks outdated and I can't find any mentions about this libs in any of popular emacs + python tutorials. What should I use to achieve easy navigation across the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>M-x speedbar</kbd> might get you what you want.

Comment: I get list of files in the current directory displayed in speedbar, but I want list of defined names (classes, functions) in the current file.

Comment: I guess you are right, I really need M+x speedbar and M+x imenu, but I can't get it working...

Comment: @VladimirMihailenco Press space on the file names expands the symbols in that file.

Comment: Been using Emacs a couple of months, and never heared of `speedbar` :) Emacs always amazes me :)

Answer (score 8):

I think [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) (Emacs Code Browser) is worth a try. I don't use it all the time but it can be very handy. Especially useful is the "ECB Methods" window which displays an outline of all members of a module.

Here is a screenshot with the ECB Methods window in the lower left corner: http://dev.pocoo.org/~gbrandl/emacs2.png.

See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsCodeBrowser.

Comment: I was able to make ECB work with Emacs 24 recently, by following the instructions here: https://github.com/alexott/ecb/tree/new-cedet. The SourceForge project has not been updated in a long time, but I think the layout customization documentation is fairly OK (http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Changing-the-ECB_002dlayout.html#Changing-the-ECB_002dlayout).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `occur` can be helpful in this case. For example, if you want to list the defined functions: `M-x occur RET def RET` should visit a buffer where the `def`'s are listed.

Comment: A great simple recommendation that works in a pinch.

Comment: Great adive indeed, this works nicely for Python: ``M-x occur RET def\b\|class\b\|=[ ]?lambda RET``